Excel - Concatenating column a and column b and summing column c
I'm trying to write a formula in Excel that would essentially concatenate the text strings in Column A and Column b, get the unique combinations for (Column A + Column B), and then get the sum of Values from Column C that are associated with that unique combination of Column A + Column B
So for example below:



A
B
C




John
Smith
3


John
Beky
4


John
Smith
7


Alice
Smith
6


Alice
" "
9


Alice
Smith
2



Hoping to get the following result below:



D
E




John  Smith
10


John  Beky
4


Alice  Smith
8


Alice " "
9



I got the CONCATENATED values on Column D through this:
=SORT(UNIQUE(CONCATENATE(A1:A6, B1:B6)), 1, -1) 

but can't seem to get the associated values for Column E
Currently trying this formula for Column E:
=SUMIF((CONCATENATE(A1:A6, B1:B6)), D1, C1:C6)

but it seems that I can't use CONCATENATE and SUM together in excel?
Is that correct?
Is there a better way to handle this?

Here is one way of doing this:


=LET(
     _Names, A1:A6&" "&B1:B6,
     SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Names,MMULT(N(_Names=TOROW(_Names)),TAKE(C1:C6,,-1)))),,-1))


Also if applicable can use GROUPBY()
=GROUPBY(A1:A6&" "&B1:B6,C1:C6,SUM,,0,-1)


Or, using BYROW()
=LET(
 _Names, A1:A6&" "&B1:B6,
 _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Names),
 SORT(HSTACK(_Uniq, BYROW(_Uniq, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=_Names)*C1:C6)))),1,-1))



Hi, apologies for the delay! This approach specifically using BYROW worked perfectly for my use case! Very elegant approach as well! Thank you! Did not realize that Excel had functionalities like HSTACK, BYROW, and referencing through LAMBDA! Thank you again!

@Maria glad to know it worked. The easier one is using GROUPBY(), for now to use the function, you will need to enable the Office Insiders in MS365

You may use Pivot Tables for this:

Jus take both text columns into rows section and numeric column into values section and that's all you need to do.
And just in case you need it, you may repeat labels in each row if you need it.

Hi, Thank you for providing this! I did not initially think that I could use Pivot Tables for the quick summary but this worked really well! Unfortunately my use case, naming conventions needed to have both Name and Surname as one entity without modifying existing data source (e.g. no new columns) to generate the right views so this was a bit outside the parameters but I will definitely look into using this method for quick analytics later on. Thank you again!
